# Only OnConnection fires in Visual Studio add-in

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm busy with a small, simple add-in, but the process seems massively complicated and badly documented.  Right now, the only event that fires in the add-in is OnConnection.  The other two I'm trying to handle just don't seem to exist.

```
    private DTE2 applicationObject;
    private SolutionEvents solutionEvents;

    public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref Array custom)
    {
        applicationObject = (DTE2)application;
        solutionEvents = ((Events2)applicationObject.Events).SolutionEvents;
        solutionEvents.Opened +=new _dispSolutionEvents_OpenedEventHandler(SolutionEvents_Opened);          
    }
    private void SolutionEvents_Opened()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Solution loaded: " + applicationObject.Solution.FullName);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm, have you tried saving a copy of `Events.SolutionEvents` locally? I'm guessing that it could 'disappear' if there's no explicit reference to it in your add-in.

This is just a guess though :)

Comment: I have now; see my modified code, and I still only get OnConnection firing, and not even the intrinsic Connect 'events' like `OnStartupComplete`

Comment: Maybe you should go the VSIP route: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/658102b9-0648-4c72-ac6d-00c7998879f4